# Action Script Trace

Tags: eclipse, actionscript

I am investigating an issue on my ActionScript/Java application, that I build using ant, and run the war in my Eclipse's tomcat. The problem is that I can't trace my app even by running the project in debbug mode. The trace("HELLO WORLD"); doesnt shot anything in Eclipse's outpout .
Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Trace should be working

Comment: Just create a simple debug panel to output your debug information to. Figuring out why legit debug output is not there would take much more time and effort, does not worth it.